# Google adsense too small can't customize size

Tags: adsense

I'm facing problem with Google Adsense size is to small. This is my code I have tried:

I have created new ads same image below: 
[create new ads screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkQVt.jpg)

This is code look like this

```
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js'></script>
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <!-- Test Ads #2016 -->
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
  style="display:block"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

The result looks like this ads still too small:

[small ads as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKcmE.png)

Please, anybody help me. Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it any custom size you can go to adsesne dashboard --> ad units then create new one there.
for your code you can just insert this

```
style="display:block"
```

instead of this

```
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
```

this will make it into block but the better way to create new one>

Comment: thank you for help but I have try your solution but still not work. Please, see code above that i have try again.